# How can I prove that 4k^2 mod 3 is always = 1

Tags: divisibility

I have a statement $n \in N, \;n^2 \mod 3 = \{0, 1\}$, which basically says that any natural number $n$ when squared will have a remainder after dividing by $3$ of either $0$ or $1$.

From here I expended my proof into two cases

$n = 2k, n^2 = 4k^2$
and
$n = 2k + 1, n^2 = 4k^2 +4k + 1$

From here I have a sense that $4 \mod 3 = 1$

and

$4 \mod 3 + 4 \mod 3 + 1 \mod 3 = 3 \mod 3 = 0$

But how do I prove this?

Comment: Consider $n=3k$ or $n=3k\pm1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting with the wrong idea. Write $n=3k$ or $n=3k+1$ or $n=3k+2$.

---

Working with residue classes modulo $3$ is of course the best strategy: if $[n]$ denotes the residue class of $n$, then $[n]=[0]$ or $[n]=[1]$ or $[n]=[2]$; since
\begin{align}
[0]^2&=[0],\\
[1]^2&=[1],\\
[2]^2&=[4]=[1],
\end{align}
the claim is proved.

This is not at all mysterious: Gauss's idea of using the residue classes is just formally forgetting the multiples of $3$ (or the modulo one uses) as computations go along.

Comment: So this sufficiently covers all natural numbers?

Comment: Well, what can the remainder of the division by $3$ be?

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ either $3|n^{2}$ or $3|(n^{2}-1)$. By division with remainder, $n=3m+r$ where $0\leq r<3$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. Now you consider the three possible values of $r$.